# Displaying html/javascript widget on a native android or IOS app

Tags: android, ios

I am not a android or IOS developer, i would like to know if it is possbile to display html/javascript ads on android or ios apps.

the same kind of ads that are displayed on websites.

Example:

```
<script id="ad" type="text/javascript" src="http://servedby.example.com/some-ad-will-appear-here"></script>
```

Comment: you can use webview or uiwebview in android or ios respectively to display a html.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. But it has to be displayed inside a view called `WebView` in Android and `UIWebView` in ios. Consider these as a simple mini browser used for browsing web content.

Comment: does the webview have to be the whole application or can it be a small part?

Comment: No it doesn't have to be whole application. It can be a small part